# DXA custom Image Schema in RichText

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.6

A problem occurred while rendering this section

Unable to map field 'formattedText' to property of type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.RichText'.

No semantic mapping found between Schema 73 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:ImageMultimediaSchema) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.MediaItem'

created:
namespace Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models and

with:
[SemanticEntity(CoreVocabulary, EntityName = "ImageMultimediaSchema", Prefix = "c", Public = true)]

class name:
public class ImageMultimediaSchema : MediaItem

till cannot add semantic mapping... anything missing? thanks

Comment: Do you register your `ImageMultimediaSchema` View Model?

Comment: hi Rick, this error fixed by register ImageMultimediaSchema thanks

Comment: Please answer your own question, then.